# OpenSSL: -pbkdf2 option no longer supported?

Tags: encryption, openssl

Until recently I was able to encrypt/decrypt files using the following commands:

Encrypt:

`openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -in un_encrypted.yml -out encrypted.data`

Decrypt:

`openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -in encrypted.data -out un_encrypted.yml`

I recently updated my Homebrew packages and it seems the `-pbkdf2` option is no longer supported? I cannot get it to work and I keep getting a help prompt on how to use the openssl command (I’ve been using the above commands for several years now). Simply removing the `-pbkdf2` option results in a corrupt output file.

Does anyone know how I can decrypt files again?

- MacOS Catalina 10.15.4
- OpenSSL 1.1.1g

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you cannot think of a language / runtime tag then you should really consider if the question belongs on StackOverflow. Voted to close -> Superuser.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Please write an answer if you did.

Comment: I did not, no. I ended up using an older version of openssl on a Linux box to decrypt my files. Crazy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

More than likely you are using the default openssl, which is LibreSSL, that comes with MacOS. LibreSSL does not support pbkdf2 as far as I could tell, so you should upgrade to full blown openssl.

To find out if you are using LibreSSL run: `openssl version`

To upgrade to openssl:

```
brew update
brew install openssl
# if it is already installed, update it:
brew upgrade openssl@1.1
```

The last step is to ensure that it is in your path before the default:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Yes when I check `openssl version` I see: `LibreSSL 2.8.3`. However, if I try to `brew install openssl` then I get the message: `Warning: openssl@1.1 1.1.1g is already installed and up-to-date. To reinstall 1.1.1g, run 'brew reinstall openssl@1.1'` so I guess Libressl is the only version I can install with Homebrew

Comment: You need to put it higher in the path so that it is seen before the LibreSSL. See the last line of my answer.

Comment: Worked! Thanks for this. Do you think it's ok to overwrite the path to include `/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin`? What does that do exactly?

Comment: You aren't overwriting the PATH, you are prepending it to the PATH. See that PATH is included there at the end. The PATH environment variable is where Operating Systems look at to see which directories to search for executables. It allows you to type `ls` and having ls run instead of typing out `/usr/bin/ls` which is where the `ls` executable is located. By prepending the openssl bin directory to the PATH the OS will find it first.

Comment: Although you might want to consider not making it the default for `openssl` given the reasons in https://security.stackexchange.com/a/112546/39798